# How to deal with merged Column Headers in R?

Tags: r, excel, dataframe

I am a beginner in the R language and I have been trying to import a particular excel sheet into R but have struggled to get it in an appropriate format.

Here is the format of the sheet I am trying to import:

[image]

When I import this sheet in R, here is how it looks like:
[image]

Is there any nice way of formatting the table in R so I can get only 1 table header where each column is named:

Nissan.Altima, Nissan.Rogue, Nissan.GTR and so on

The way I read the excel sheet into R was to use the read_excel() function

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

One option is to read the data with `skip = 1` to skip the first row

```
library(readr)
df1 <- read_excel('file.xlsx', skip = 1)
```

then read the first line with `readLines`

```
lines <- scan(text = readLines('file.xlsx', n = 1), what = "", quiet = TRUE)
names(df1)[-1] <- paste0(names(df1)[-1], ".", rep(lines, c(4, 4, 2)))
```